# Speed of least common multiple algorithms (java)

Tags: java, performance

I'm trying to make an Euler problem: for now my speed-defining step is counting the least common multiple of two numbers. So, which one of these methods is faster? Why?

```
    public static int lcm(int a, int b){
        for(int test = a; true; test += a){
            if(test % b == 0)
                return test;
        }
    }
```

or

```
    public static int lcm(int a, int b){
        for(int i = 1; true; i++){
            if(i*a % b == 0)
                return i*a;
        }
    }
```

What I think is the fundamental question here is which one is faster process, multiplication or addition.

Thanks.

(Before asking me to show the rest of my code/saying I should not concentrate on this part of my program: my question is not how to get the answer for the problem but how to make this part faster.)

Comment: These two methods should be almost identical - they are doing exactly the same thing (as people say, optimize algorithm first, then optimize your code). The only difference is that second uses multiplication versus addition which should be a tiny margin slower than first one.

Answer (score 1):

Roughly spoken, to create fast code avoid everything that will result in slow assembler code. This includes:

- Temporaries (here: loop variable)
- Constants (here: true)
- Condition checking (here: true)
- Multiplications (here: i * a)
- Modulo (here: test % b)
- Don't rely on compiler optimization

Temporary, modulo and one comparision is inherent by algorithm, thus anavoidable. So it would result in something like this:

```
public int euler(int a, int b) {
    int test = a;
    while (test % b != 0) {
        test += a;
    }
    return test;
}
```

If you slightly modify (numerically) the algorithm to an equivalent equation, you can eliminate multiplications completely:

```
public int own(int a, int b) {
    int x = a;
    for (int y = 0;; x += a) {
        while (y < x) {
            y += b;
        }
        if (x == y)
            break;
    }
    return x;
}
```

By the way: If you're going to find the LCM of large numbers, maybe you'll better use Euclid's algorithm for GCD. Thus LCM(a, b) = a * b / GCD(a, b). An efficient implementation is already in Java class BigInteger.gcd().

Comment: Results in an infinite loop in the case that b is 0

Comment: You're right - it's efficient to ignore useless cases. We're talking about effiency not stability.

Comment: IMHO, the first requirement is to have a *correct* program. You could check the arguments outside the loop.

Comment: The program is correct inside correct parameters. Even the algorithm in the question throws on b = 0, you can report this to Euler himself ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It is too early to comment or predict which one is faster.

Your both program will take same number of iterations as explained below.

In case 1, you are increasing each step by a.

In case 2, you are increasing multiple by 1 which is same as increasing by a.

Let us take case 1

```
public static int lcm(int a, int b){
    for(int test = a; true; test += a){
        if(test % b == 0)
            return test;
    }
}
```

You have avoid multiply operation in `if` statement and also in `return`.

In case 2, you are using `increment operator` and multiply in `if` and `return`.
It is multiplying at each if condition.

Increment operation can be optimized by using increment operation of assembly and thus it can be faster than adding by a.

The extra time in case 1 is of addition by a.

In case 2, extra time in case 2 is of increment and multiply at each if condition and at return on successful if condition.

If multiply is slower than addition, then case 2 is slightly slower than case 1. You may notice the slight difference only on large number of test run.

Please note that there are other factors too which can affect the performance.

So, before coming to final conclusion, both of the code must be profiled to see the difference in terms of time taken.